# Pop up a View from a Button containing information but keeping the current View behind it: Swift implementation

Tags: ios, swift, popup

I am finishing my career project and I want to make some UI improvements on the application I developed in Swift for iOS.

The application does not have any explicit explanation of how it works and I'd like to detail it in a pop-up View called from an information button in the Navigation Bar. I'd like some kind of View similar to the Notification Alerts, which pop-up in front of the current view and they disappear by pressing another button. I give you an example image:

[image: Representation of a View popping up in front of another View]

I want this button to be available from any Tab View (I've got three views). Any idea of how to manage that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First, go to IB and create a new View Controller. In the Attributes Inspector, click on the dropdown next to Size and click Freeform. Set the size to what you want. Then click Use Preferred Explicit size.

Control-drag from your info button to the new VC you created. Click on the segue, then go to the attributes inspector and change the segue type to 'Present As Popover.' Change the segue identifier to whatever you want. I named it popover.

Create a new class for your popover view and assign it to the VC you created. It doesn't need any code at the moment.

In your presenting VC (Tab Bar), add UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate to your class definition. Then add this function:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}
```

Next, in your Tab Bar VC, add this code to your prepareForSegue method:

```
if segue.identifier == "popover" {

        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! PopoverVC // whatever you named the class
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        controller.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self

    }
```

That should do it.